# In Excel, using VBA, how do I take the "path+filename+extension" and change the extension?

Tags: excel, vba

Have a program that's dynamically generating an Excel file and a csv. The excel file has VBA code that loads the csv data "on load" and I want to dynamically call that csv by having the csv file have the same filename, but just the different extension. So, based on my understanding this if the xls file was here:

```
C:\directory\filename.xls
```

This VBA code:

```
Function GetFullName() As String

 GetFullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName 

End Function
```

Would result in

```
GetFullName() = "C:\directory\filename.xls"
```

So, if that's correct ([source of code](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/WorkbookPath.htm)), how do I replace ".xls" with ".csv" and then insert that value into a file call. Or for example, to keep it simple, the file has VBA that prints a PDF using this code; which would require me to use the GetFullName, and change ".xls" to ".pdf":

```
Sub PrintPDF()

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\directory\filename.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False _

End Sub
```

Hope the problem is clear, if there's a better solution concept, I'm open to it. If you've got questions, just let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace could be exactly what you want:

```
Function GetFullNameCSV() As String

 GetFullNameCSV = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xls",".csv")  

End Function
```

You can extend this by including the extension you want like so:

```
sFileName = GetNewExt("pdf")

Function GetNewExt(Ext As String) As String

 GetNewExt = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xls","." & Ext)  

End Function
```

Comment: +1 Cool, did you test it, or just guessing it'll work? Also, how would I insert GetFullNameCSV() into the Filename attribute in the PrintPDF() example? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't test, but I am very familiar with Replace. I have sketched out a way of using this.

Comment: +1 Okay, just checking, figured so, just don't have an install of Excel to test it right now -- that said, think it's possible I'm not understanding your code, or more likely, your not understanding the core of my question. How do I take << Filename:= "GetFullNameCSV()" >> and have it read as << Filename:= "C:\directory\filename.pdf" >>. The reference to Filename is taken from the "Sub PrintPDF()" example in my question. Meaning I'm guessing I can't just plug "GetFullNameCSV()" in as the filename location without some special formatting. Right, or no? Again, thank you!!

Comment: @blunders You can just plug it in.  The "special formatting" is supplied by the function, which returns a string, one exactly equivalent to the filename string you specified.

Comment: @Doug Glancy: +1 Thanks, guess I just got confused filenames that were being inserted using string string concatenation.

Comment: It's not universal method. As we say, it isnt foolproof.
Full path also may contain ".xls" ("c:/my.xls projects/filename.xls") or extension may be different (.xlsm, .xlsb)