# VBA Error: "Compile error: Expected End Sub"

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to pass "GetFullNamePDF()" to the Filename attribute, but getting the following error: "Compile error: Expected End Sub"

```
Sub PrintPDF()

    Function GetFullNamePDF() As String
        GetFullNameCSV = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", ".pdf")
    End Function

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "GetFullNamePDF()", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties _
        :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

I know nothing about VBA, and got the above code from a [question I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466998/in-excel-using-vba-how-do-i-take-the-pathfilenameextension-and-change-the-e), but was unable to test at the time. Guessing the error has to do with the function, since the code works without the function added and the filepath/name hard coded.

Idea of the code is to dynamically use the filename of itself to name the path and file for the PDF. If you have any questions, just comment -- thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't nest a function inside a procedure. You need to move it above:

```
Function GetFullNamePDF() As String
    GetFullNameCSV = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", ".pdf")
    'This should be
    GetFullNamePDF = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", ".pdf")
End Function

Sub PrintPDF()

     'Remove the quotes from GetFullNamePDF
     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        GetFullNamePDF(), Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties _
        :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to read the code and make sure everything is right; wise I code say my code was better, but never used Excel's VBA.

Answer (score 1):

It is illegal to declare a function within a sub.
It should look like this:

```
Function GetFullNamePDF() As String 
    GetFullNamePDF = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", ".pdf") 
End Function 


Sub PrintPDF() 
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _ 
        "GetFullNamePDF()", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties _ 
        :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Function GetFullNamePDF() As String
    GetFullNamePDF = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".xlsm", ".pdf")
End Function

Sub PrintPDF()
    Dim sFileName As Variable

    sFileName=GetFullNamePDF()

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        sFilename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties _
        :=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: @Remou: There's no reference to "sFilename" in the code, don't think that'd work.

Comment: @Blunder Do you forget that I wrote this function? I am very, very familiar with VBA (check the users on the VBA tag). It is by no means uncommon to set a variable to the result of a function, it makes debugging much easier. There is an error in your rewriting of the function, which I will correct.

Comment: @Remou: You're correct, it would work -- what would be the reason to set a a variable to the result of a function?

Comment: As I said, it makes debugging much easier, it can make code easier to read as well.

Comment: @RolandTumble If you are getting into coding problems at that level, consider ActiveSheet, which may or may not return an object.

Comment: @Remou Haven't had to deal with ActiveSheet, but I've run into a few of those "may or may not..." functions. It's just that my background in VB(3|5|6) says "ALWAYS use Option Explicit"--it's another thing that makes debugging easier--and I didn't see the Dim statement (it's there now, of course).

Comment: @RolandTumble If you are going to have problems with lack of declarations in code snippets, you may need a long time to go through StackOverflow :)

Comment: @Remou True, too true. I only chose to comment because of the existing "will it/won't it work" comment thread. The elipsis were meant to imply that it was sort of a throwaway comment....