# In vba How to change extension when saving file, don't know exact filename

Tags: excel, vba, replace, file-extension

My issue is this.

I read in a series of filenames using a wildcard, so that the end of the filename is unknown, and the extension is either .xls or .xlsx. So, the wildcard is something like :

beginningOfFilename_`*.xls`*

I then want to take each file, after I have manipulated it, and save it with the same name, but as a .csv (comma seperated value file). In vba for excel, can I just specify the format and it will take care of the extension, or do I have to somehow pull off the( unknown) extension, and append .csv

If the second case is neccessary how would you approach this problem, I don't know where to start, since part of the filename is unknown, and I am not sure how to manipulate strings in vba.

I'm a VBA beginner.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It appears as though the answer here could work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466998/in-excel-using-vba-how-do-i-take-the-pathfilenameextension-and-change-the                                                  If I was able to specify .xls and .xlsx for the replace

Comment: Yes, you can. Where are you having a problem with the sample code?

Comment: I don't know what I am replacing .xls or .xlsx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line you want is :

```
Mid(sFile, 1, InStrRev(sFile, ".")) & "csv"
```

Where sFile is the file name with any extension.

Comment: I wouldn't have been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

```
Split(sFile, ".")(0) & ".csv"
```

where `sFile` is the filename

Answer (score 1):

To get a path and name of your file without extension use.

```
Dim StrFileName as string

StrFileName= split(ThisWorkbook.fullName,".xls")(0)
```

Now save your Csv using StrFileName content.

[]´s

Comment: I don't know whether the extension is .xls .xlsx so I can't do this.